# Printing line by line output to GUI in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I want to print my stdout to GUI in python. I am using Tkinter.
This is what I is working for me

```
def get_likes_button():
    output = subprocess.Popen(['python', "getLikes.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    s1 = output.stdout.read()
    text.delete("1.0",END)
    text.insert(INSERT,s1)
```

But, I am getting the whole output at once.
What I want is that the GUI should print the output iteratively just like it prints on terminal.

So, I tried this, but it gave me an error on clicking the button

```
def get_likes_button():
    text.delete("1.0",END)
    with subprocess.Popen(['python', "getLikes.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as output:
        s1 = output.stdout.read()
        text.insert(INSERT,s1)
```

The error is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "gui.py", line 88, in get_likes_button
with subprocess.Popen(['python', "getLikes.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as output:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Can you please suggest me what to do?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14883648/4203871) for an example of how to redirect `stdout` to a widget using threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Popen` does not support context managers (i.e. `with`) hence the error. But also note that there is no practical difference between the 2 versions of your code.

You could instead read line by line:

```
def get_likes_button():
    child = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'getLikes.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    text.delete("1.0",END)
    for line in iter(child.stdout.readline, ''):
        text.insert(INSERT, line)
    child.stdout.close()
    child.wait()
```

The line `for line in iter(child.stdout.readline, ''):` is used to work around the buffering that would be experienced if the loop had been `for line in child.stdout:`.

---

**Update**

Try revising the code as follows:

```
def get_likes_button():
    child = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', 'getLikes.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    text.delete("1.0",END)
    for line in iter(child.stdout.readline, ''):
        text.insert(INSERT, line)
        text.see(END)
        text.update_idletasks()
    child.stdout.close()
    child.wait()
```

The changes are:

1. Use the `-u` python option for unbuffered output in the child,
2. Call `text.see(END)` to scroll the text window to the bottom after
   each insert,
3. Call `text.update_idletasks()` to give Tkinter a chance to update
   the text widget.

This might help to avoid using threads, but the one down side of this is that the rest of the GUI will be unresponsive while your callback is executing. That might be acceptable if your child process is short lived, perhaps not if the child runs for an extended period - it depends on your application.

Comment: what is `p` in the last 2 lines?

Comment: @ronilp: thanks for noticing, it should of course be `child`. Fixed.

Comment: i made getLikes.py as `for i in range(500000):
 print i` I tried running it both on terminal and GUI. I am getting a delayed output on the GUI and instantaneous output on terminal

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `subprocess.Popen` can be used within `with` clause. I think `check_output` is what you need:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'getLikes.py'])
```

Comment: So you mean that I should use     ''with subprocess.check_output(['python', "getLikes.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as output:''    ?

Comment: When I tried that I am getting this error :  stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.

Comment: No. No `with` clause. Just this.

Comment: You mean just this and then          s1 = output.stdout.read()         
    text.insert(INSERT,s1)  ?

Comment: Just `output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'getLikes.py'])`, nothing else. The output should be OK.

Comment: i tried doing `output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'getLikes.py'])` then `text.insert(INSERT,output)`

Comment: Isn't the terminal output stored in `output`?

Comment: Actually I got the issue, I need to run both `insert in GUI` command and `get output from stdout` in 2 different threads and use a queue with syncronization to keep printing to the GUI. I just don't know how to do that in python.